# CSS Animation resets to first keyframe at end

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I have the following code that animates the background position for an element to create a keyframe animation. It's 12 frames and the image is 1536px.

However even though I have `-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;` the animation resets back to the first frame at the end... How do I stop this?

HTML:

```
<div class="sequence animate"></div>
```

CSS:

```
div.sequence
{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url('./img/sequence.png');
}

div.sequence.animate
{
    -webkit-animation: boxopen 4s steps(12);
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes boxopen {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position: -1536px;}
}
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zpsa37m3/1/

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you were looking for.

Comment: Ahh! My bad. I think you want to stop it at the last keyframe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your image repeats so by frame 12 the image is entirely offset to the left and you're seeing the start of it repeated. Simply stop the animation after 11 steps:

```css
div.sequence
{
    width: 128px;
    height: 128px;
    background: url('http://i60.tinypic.com/1otwkg.png');
}

div.sequence.animate
{
    -webkit-animation: boxopen 6s steps(11); /* 11 steps not 12 */
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

@-webkit-keyframes boxopen {
    from {background-position: 0;}
    to {background-position: -1408px;} /* stop at the left of frame 12 */
}
```

```html
<div class="sequence animate"></div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/zpsa37m3/3/